# How to get a mosh-server secret key from the running process?

Tags: ssh

I have standard mosh setup, a mosh-client on `local.machine`, and a mosh-server on `remote.machine`.

I've still got access to both mosh-client, and the mosh-server processes, both are still running.

Is there any way of extracting the 22 byte key string from either of those? This would be to solve the use case of losing access to the running mosh-client, and reattaching to the mosh-server process at a later date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, and has been brought up on the #mosh channel on irc.freenode.net. It is considered a too big security vulnerability to implement (though the source is free...).

It does seem to me like the problem you are having has already been solved by screen[1] and tmux[2]. Which enables you to attach and detach from running terminal sessions. So when you lose your connection you: log back in, kill the running mosh-server, and reattach to your old terminal session.

[1]https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/
[2]http://tmux.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access or access to the user that started mosh on the client machine, you can pull the key from `/proc/PID_OF_MOSH_CLIENT/environ` and the IP address and port number from `/proc/PID_OF_MOSH_CLIENT/cmdline`.  However, I have not been able to connect a second client to the server with this information.